# Is it possible to update location of Point class?

Tags: java, point

I've got a particle with a `Point` field. I would like to grab this `Point`, create an imaginary square of points around it (only integers), and add the all points to a list as long as they're not already in the list `getstuck`. This is approximately how I would like it to look:

```
public void pointStuck(Particle particle) {
    Point ps = particle.getPoint();
    for (int i = -3; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = -3; j < 4; j++) {
            ps += (i,j);
            if (getstuck.contains(ps) == false) {
                getstuck.add(ps);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the syntax `ps += (i,j);` doesn't work, is there anything close to this I could use instead?

I know I can just grab the particle point every time and then add `i` and `j` separately like this;

```
Point ps = new Point(particle.getX()+i, particle.getY()+j)
```

but this makes my code inefficient. I want to call the `point` from the `particle` just once, and then just update it for every `forloop` without having to call for the `point` again.

Comment: I assume that `i` and `j` are int coordinates in the class `Point`?

Comment: `ps.x += i;` and `ps.y += j;`

Comment: I suggest you learn how to find and read the Java API documentation. A google search for "java point" will get you started.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if you mean https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html , I've already read it but didn't find a solution for my problem. Might have missed something.

Comment: See my answer which explains how you can find the answer to your question from the doc you linked. I hope this helps you understand better how to read the Java API docs. Finding the answers to your questions in the documentation will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Will try and practice that, thank you for the explanation below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide setters for the coordinates `x`, `y`. Instead of creating a new instance again, you set values to the instance you have already obtained:

```
ps.setX(ps.getX() + i);
ps.setY(ps.getY() + j);
```

Note that it makes the class mutable. There are no longer final coordinates.

---

The statement `ps += (i,j);` is completely incorrect. You can't build an object by `(i, j)`. You can't overload the `+=` operator for the `Point` either.

But you could bypass operator overloading by a static method `merge(Point a, Point b)`. It makes less sense since you need to form the second parameter and pass it anyway.

A method `merge(Point p, int x, int y)` is not an object-oriented approach.

Comment: Thank you! I worked from what you said and used the `setLocation()`-method for `Point`: `ps.setLocation(ps.getX()+i, ps.getY()+j);`

Answer (score 1):

If we're discussing `java.awt.Point` objects then the x and y fields of a Point object are nothing but public fields, and so you can simply update the x and y fields of your Point object directly:

```
ps.x += i; 
for (int j = -3; j < 4; j++) {
    ps.y += j;
    if (!getstuck.contains(ps)) {
        getstuck.add(ps);
    }
}
```

Comment: One **could** recommend to "program to the interface" `Point2D` and use [Point2D#setLocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#setLocation-double-double-), but this is far less concise than the `+=` in this case, and (more importantly) : if the objects are indeed `Point` objects, this could be misleading, as it *suggests* `double` coordinates which in fact are only `int`. (The `Point extends Point2D` thing is a reasonable way for handling the "legacy" `Point` class, but may have some caveats...)

Comment: See edit, as you can see in the output, the different ways of updating the point doesn't give the same result. I compared my first inefficient solution with your presented solution @Hovercraft-Full-Of-Eels

Answer (score 0):

You can answer these kinds of questions by reading the Java API documentation for the `Point` class. Start by googling "java point" which should give you a link to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html.

Then scroll down to fields and you will see descriptions of both `int x` and `int y`. Since these show up in the documentation, you automatically know that you can access them. To check whether they are public or protected click on the name of the field for more details. [When you click on `x`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#x), you will see that it is public. This means you can access it directly and modify it in any way you wish as the other answers show.

Reading this type of documentation is a critical skill as you learn how to program in Java.